# Add two differents items in same column using loop in sybase

Tags: sql, sybase

Suppose there different companies which use different currencies in their work, TCS uses USD as well as GBP. Now we have column like this

```
Company   Amount      Currency
TCS-      200          USD
Infosys   50           USD
TCS       100          USD
TCS       50           GBP
INFOSYS   100          GBP
TCS       100          GBP
```

Now I need a query with resulting column which will add the total of these companies and show like this:

```
Company   Total Amount
TCS      300USD+150GBP
Infosys  100USD+100GBP
```

It should be like this, we make two local variables. In one we add the values of one currency, in other we add the values of two currency(usd , gbp) Variable i.e. usd will check if the value is in US Dollars then it will add to the previous value in USD. Similarly gbp will add values of type GBP i.e.(200+100) USD and (100+50)GBP. Now we concatenate these variables and add in a third variable (300USD + 150GBP). Now this third variable will be displayed as a result in total column.

Comment: Are you storing several values in the same column/row?

Comment: The column revenue has different types of values .Yes, need several values in the same column "Total" revenues.

Comment: Your table has (at least) two columns: One for the company and one for the combination of value and currency, yes? (If so, then your table design is not good, because you store two things, value and currency, in one column where you need them separate.) And the latter column's values consist of an integer followed immediately (i.e. no blank etc.) by a three-letter currency code, correct?

Comment: Actually one column comprises of only value(amount like 200) and other column tells the currency(USD,GBP,etc). So , the columns are different in table, but I need a column that will concatenate the sum of values and show in single column

Answer (score 0):

You want one line per company, so you'd group by company. But in these lines you want to show aggregated data per company and currency. That's another grouping, so it's actually two steps you must take.

The first step is easy, get the sums per company and currency:

```
select company, currency, sum(amount)
from mytable
group by company, currency;
```

Now, how to get these totals concatenated in a string? Sybase provides the aggregation function LIST for this (see here: [http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/...](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1604/doc/html/jcu1290709667623.html)). Hence:

```
select company, list(currency_total || currency, '+') as total_amount
from
(
  select company, currency, sum(amount) as currency_total
  from mytable
  group by company, currency;
) totals
group by company
order by company;
```